# How do I wire a combo switched outlet from a duplex outlet and control the top outlet with the switch? Maintain hot on both bottoms

Tags: electrical

I have installed a duplex outlet behind a TV on my outside bar and the live wire enters that box from a 10/2 wire. I have ran a 12/3 wire from that box to a combo switch box to control whatever I have plugged in to the top outlet. I’d like to keep both outlet bottoms hot and allow the switch to control the power to the top of the outlet behind the TV.. I will be plugging in light strings behind the TV and want to control those with the combo switch. I appreciate any help.. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a quad outlet (two duplexes?) Otherwise "both bottoms" does not make sense. Do you want to control both tops with the switch, or only one?  By "combo switch" do you mean a switch and a receptacle in one dual-gang box, or a single-gang with one switch and one receptacle, or what? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Pictures tend to be helpful to make things clear.

Comment: 2 outlets that I have removed the bridge clips from. I want the switch in one to operate a single outlet in the other, all while both bottoms of the respective outlets are always hot.The combo switch is composed of a switch on top and receptacle  on bottom. The main power comes in to the dual outlet that I have removed the tabs on to operate independently with the combo switch. Sorry

Comment: An annotated picture or drawing of what you're attempting to do would be most helpful. Please [edit] it into your question. Just hit the "sun & mountain" icon to add the picture, or simply drag & drop the image into the text edit box. A picture is, after all, worth 1000 words!

Comment: A couple of incidental things: 1) The ground wire should be connected to *the box's* ground screw.  It can be extended to the outlet but that particular outlet is self-grounding, so if the metal box is properly grounded that's enough.  That particular combo switch is also not outdoor-rated.  You'll at least have a good wet-in-use cover on it I hope.

Answer (score 2):

##### Caveats

The 10/2 cable needs a 15A or 20A GFCI breaker on it. If it's a 30A breaker you can't put regular outlets on it.  I hope it's #10 cable because of the distance to the panel and not because there is or was a 30A load there.  Being outside *and* at a bar, it needs to be GFCI but you can't split a GFCI outlet the way you want so you need to use a GFCI breaker.  There are other ways, but I'll keep it simple.

##### The answer

Assuming the 12/3 is black, red, white (and assuming you know how to manage grounds, I won't cover that in this answer).

Behind the TV, connect the 10/2 white to the 12/3 white and the neutral side of the outlet.  Break the tab on the live side of the outlet, connect the 10/2 black to the 12/3 black and the bottom live connector.  Connect the 12/3 red to the top live connector.

At the switch, connect black and white as per the switch instructions, and red to the switched side of the switch. The red wire supplies switched power back to the top half of the TV outlet.

Again, the #10 cable worries me ... you can't use  30A breaker for any of this.

Answer (score 0):

You only needed to remove the clips on the hot side, if you removed the neutral side as well you'll have to jumper that.

So, from the always-hot bottom outlet you bring white & black of a 12/3 cable to the "combo switch and outlet."

The black connects to the hot on the outlet and to one switch terminal, the white connects to the neutral on the outlet, and the red connects to the other switch terminal. If the device came pre-configured to switch its own outlet, you'll need to consult the instructions for how to disable that (probably also breaking tabs) though it might be as simple as connecting the black to the outlet, leaving it connected to the switch via the tab, and connecting the red to the other side of the switch.

At the originating outlet you connect the red switched hot to the hot side of the upper receptacle. If you broke the neutral tab run a white jumper from one neutral screw to the other, or pigtail to a wire-nut if your outlet is screw-connect (one wire per) rather than "screw-and-clamp" connect (2 wires per.) That methodology depending on terminal type will also apply to the always hot feed from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

On previous box with duplex:
Break only the brass tab on the duplex.
Connect incoming and outgoing blacks to bottom brass screw (by pigtail if necessary).
Connect incoming and outgoing whites to white screw(s).
Connect red to top brass screw.
Connect ground wires together and pigtail to box, and to receptacle (to receptacle optional if "self grounding").

On combo box (with [Eaton TR274W)](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.TR274W.html):
Connect white wire to silver screw.
Connect red to brass screw.
Connect black to either dark colored screw.
Connect ground wire to j-box ground screw.